# When using EditorFor() on a collection, is it possible to return the index of the current iteration?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'm using an EditorFor()

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.documentInfo.destinations)%>
```

instead of a foreach

```
<% foreach (var item in Model.documentInfo.destinations)
   {
       Html.RenderPartial("Document/Destination", item);
   }
%>
```

Is it possible to get the numerical index of which item the EditorFor() is displaying?

**Edit:** I would like to use the index inside the editor template to generate custom incremental names/IDs for my fields in the template.

Comment: Where would you like to use this index? I'm guessing inside a template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that no, you cannot access the numerical index of a field in a collection generated with `EditorFor()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a strongly-type template of type `IList`.

```
<%@Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IList>" %>

<% for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) { %>
    <h1><%:Model[i]%></h1>
<% } %>
```